# Div not scrollable on mobile (document.ontouchmove)

Tags: javascript, mobile, touchmove

I have a simple Website with an ontouchmove-handler on the whole document-object.
On this website there a couple of div-elements with a scrollbar (overflow: auto; height: 200px).

**Theses div-elements are not scrollable on mobile devices.**

If i remove the ontouchmove-handler from the document-object then it works perfectly.

Mybe there is a simple solution where i can use the ontouchmove-handler and make the scrollable-div-elements?

Comment: We will need to see code. If you use `preventDefault` it wouldn't scroll anyhow, but we _need_ to see your code. And the simple solution is: _don't implement scrolling yourself_ - if your div has an `overflow: scroll`, it will be scrollable on all devices by default.

Comment: Your are my man. If i remove preventDefault, it works like charm. Perfekt!!! Thank your somethinghere!

Comment: no problem :) The default events for `mousemove` is scrolling, btw :)